# How do I make a scanner input store the last 2 values indefinitely?

Tags: java, input

My question is  - if I have for example two declared variables

```
    int number1=0
    int number2=0
```

And I have the input(assuming I declared the class and method beforehand):

```
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 20");
        number1 = scanner.nextInt();
```

How do I make it so that it stores the last 2 values that were made so I can use those? I know that with these two lines of code I can store a value in `number1`, but I want `number1` and `number2` to constantly be the last two values that were inputted. Do I use a loop?

I'm still a beginner and trying to understand so perhaps there's something I'm completely missing about how the scanner works.

Comment: If you need to ask many times to insert the two number then you can use a loop to do it. For every iteration, you will overwrite number1 and number2 with the new inputs

Comment: Is there any point at that you want to stop asking for new input and continue?

Comment: @FelixGerber no, these lines are in a switch so you can keep coming back to the scanner input and keep overwriting these values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required logic here is:

- Copy the value from `number1` to `number2`;
- Copy the value from `scanner.nextInt()` to `number1`.

So your values shift along one position. This can be implemented as follows:

```
number2 = number1;            // Now number1 == number2 temporarily.
number1 = scanner.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a temporary value,

```
int temp= scanner.nextInt();
number2= number1;
number1=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
import java.util.*;

public class WhateverItIsYouWantToDo {
    private static int number1;
    private static int number2;
    private static boolean blank = true;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 20");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            if (blank == true) {
                number1 = console.nextInt();
                blank = false;
            } else {
                number2 = number1;
                number1 = console.nextInt();
            }
        } while (true); //note: this means the code will not terminate. you  
    // might want to make some way to make the code terminate at some point, 
    // or just do it manually.
}
```

The contents of the main method ought to do it. If you want to do that in a different method, just copy and paste the contents of the main into said other method.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean with

> the last 2 values

I thinking about two scenarios:

1.- You want to continue asking the user for new Input until something happens like a special inputvalue than you could do a loop like this:

```
    int number1=0;
    int number2=0;
    boolean continueAsking = true;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(continueAsking)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 20");
        number1 = scan.nextInt();
        scan.reset();

        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 20");
        number2 = scan.nextInt();
        scan.reset();

        if(/*number1 or number2 is something you want*/)
        {
            continueAsking = false;
        }
    }
```

2.- Another way of what you want to do(I'm sure this more what you want than way 1) could be copy `number1` to `number2` and than set number 1 the new value.

```
int input = scanner.nextInt();
number2 = number1;
number1 = input;
```